# one log4net log file for many applications

Tags: vb.net, log4net

I have two scheduled tasks which write to the same log4net log file.

When one task is running it writes to the log file successfully. However, when both are running; the first to start will write to the log file and the second to start will not.

Do you have to have one log file per app? I have read the documentation but cant find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that the best way to go unless you only run one app and expect the other app not to run, while one app is using the file the other app may not write to it so you either need to use thread pool in order to control the application that accessing each log or create a separate logfiles I  personally would use database in this situation.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any risk having a single log file? The only problem is that only one app can write at atime.

Comment: the risk is loosing some of the log

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to write to the same file from two processes it is possible to use a [different locking model](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.LockingModel.html) than the default to allow this. Here are the existing models in log4net:

- [ExclusiveLock](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.ExclusiveLock.html): locks the file exclusively, for one process only
- [MinimalLock](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.MinimalLock.html): locks the file during the least amount of time possible, making changing/deleting the file during logging possible
- [InterProcessLock](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.InterProcessLock.html): allows synchronization between processes

So it is definitely possible to have multiple processes write to the same file without losing info. However, as COLD TOLD said and as the log4net documentation recommends:

> All locking strategies have issues and you should seriously consider
>   using a different strategy that avoids having multiple processes
>   logging to the same file.

Comment: True. I just like to add that you'd have the same issues when logging from different AppDomains (within the same process).

Comment: @Christian.K : Good point. I didn't think about the different AppDomains because I don't use them that much. I usually try and use a forwarding appender - which buffers and may help alleviate the problem when I do. Do you have some experience logging across domains? Can buffering help alongside the locking mechanism?